# How to setup_lifitng with custom types (aka how to define a "relator")?

Tags: isabelle

In the Isabelle/HOL, I would like to work with two custom `typedef`s that build on top of each other, and show that both of them instantiate certain type classes (e.g. from `HOL.Rings`). I do not understand what definitions or facts are required to properly call `setup_lifiting` in this case. Moreover, I would like to understand what precise purpose this keyword serves after declaring a `typedef` (currently I simply try to mimick the structure of existing work) and what the so-called *relators* are which are used in the process. Neither the *locale* nor the *typeclass* PDF tutorials go into much detail on this command.

For explicitness, consider the [AFP entry implementing polynomials](https://www.isa-afp.org/browser_info/current/AFP/Polynomials/Polynomials.html), which schematically defines monomials as

```
type_synonym 'v monom_list = "('v × nat)list" 
[...]
typedef (overloaded) 'v monom = "Collect (monom_inv :: ...)"
```

for an adequate invariant `monom_inv`. The same entry proceeds to define polynomials as

```
type_synonym ('v,'a)poly = "('v monom × 'a)list"
```

and also defines a suitable invariant `poly_inv`.

After the typedef of `'v monom`, it appears to be no problem to call `setup_lifting type_definition_monom` as the necessary *relators* (?) for the underlying types (in particular lists) are part of the standard library. (Please correct if this is a misunderstanding of what's actually going on.)

However, after a new `typedef (overloaded) ('v, 'a) polyq = "Collect (poly_inv :: ...)"` (which is not part of the AFP entry cited above), things are different. Now, calling

```
setup_lifting type_definition_polyq
```

yields a warning which reads: *Generation of a parametrized correspondence relation failed. Reason: No relator for the type "Polynomials.monom" found.*

**Do I need to address this issue to afterwards call for example `instatiation polyq :: (...) comm_semiring_1`? If yes, how can I go about defining a relator for the `monom` type?**

Answer (score 1):

The `setup_lifting` is only useful if you intend to use the lifting-and-transfer framework, for the details of which you can read [Huffman and Kuncar's CPP paper](https://www21.in.tum.de/%7Ekuncar/documents/huffman-kuncar-cpp2013.pdf). Some recent progress in this framework is mostly related to bounded natural functors, for which you can have a look at this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.05348).

Proposing suitable relators requires insight of the data type. Here `setup_lifting` gives us some relatively easy relator theorems for free.

(Answer from the Isabelle Zulip Chat.)